# Reading a filestream issue

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I am trying to read a file from my computer and output its contents into a literal control.  It gives the error : `Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`  This is my first time using FileStream and I'm not 100% about all of the syntax for VB, or if there's even a community-preferred way of reading from a file, but could somebody help me out with this error?

This is the code:

```
 Using fs As New FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Try
                    Dim fileLength As Integer = CInt(fs.Length)
                    Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte() {fileLength}
                    Dim count As Integer
                    Dim sum As Integer = 0

                    While ((count = fs.Read(buffer, sum, fileLength - sum)) > 0)
                        sum = sum + count
                    End While
                    litOutput.Text = buffer.ToString()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'TODO: log error
                End Try
            End Using
```

Comment: How about [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  There is also a version that takes an encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte() {fileLength}
```

It declares an array of 1 byte in which you try to store the length of your file. Probably you have `Option Strict` set to `Off` and thus you could go away without noticing immediately the problem.

Of course, if your file is of a reasonable length and it is a simple textfile then there is no need for this loop. Just use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines(v=vs.110).aspx), and by the way, your code read all your data in a single call because the last parameter of `FileStream.Read` is the quantity of bytes to read from file and the expression `fileLength - sum` produces a request to read all the bytes in a single call

Instead if you want to read your file in chunks of certain sizes then 
probably you need

```
Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Try
        Dim chunkSize = 2000
        Dim fileLength As Integer = CInt(fs.Length)
        Dim buffer(fileLength) as Byte
        Dim blockSize(chunkSize) as Byte
        Dim count As Integer = -1
        Dim pos As Integer = 0

        While count <> 0
            count = fs.Read(blockSize, 0, chunkSize-1)
            Array.Copy(blockSize, 0, buffer, pos, count)
            pos += count
        End While

        litOutput.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
```

Notice that this code assumes that your file is a Text file with UTF8 encoding.
It this is not the case then you could try with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` or `Encoding.Unicode.GetString`

Comment: Thanks, had no idea `File.ReadAllText` was a thing.  Much simpler!